# Unable to pause activity exception in android

Tags: android, service, onpause

Hi I am developing small android application. So my application contains following things. 3 Activities consider A1, A2, A3. A1 is my launcher activity. my application also contains one background service. So when I click on button inside A1 it will start background service.

Inside background service I am starting A2. I am also doing some calculations in service so after those calculations i am starting activity A3 from service only. SO my problem is here when I start service from A1 it will open A2 from service. If I click back from there(A2 to A1) it will come back to A1. But in case of (A1 -> service -> A2 -> A3(this also started from service)) if i click on back it will causes unable to pause activity exception error. It will not resume A1.

When I start activity from service I am using `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`. Where is the problem? need Help Thank you

See this is my error log:

```
01-17 14:45:03.689: E/AndroidRuntime(27805): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-17 14:45:03.689: E/AndroidRuntime(27805): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity { ABC/ ABC.map.MapActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException
01-17 14:45:03.689: E/AndroidRuntime(27805):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2709)
01-17 14:45:03.689: E/AndroidRuntime(27805):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
01-17 14:45:03.689: E/AndroidRuntime(27805):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2643)
01-17 14:45:03.689: E/AndroidRuntime(27805):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:124)
01-17 14:45:03.689: E/AndroidRuntime(27805):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1159)
01-17 14:45:03.689: E/AndroidRuntime(27805):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-17 14:45:03.689: E/AndroidRuntime(27805):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-17 14:45:03.689: E/AndroidRuntime(27805):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4436)
01-17 14:45:03.689: E/AndroidRuntime(27805):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-17 14:45:03.689: E/AndroidRuntime(27805):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-17 14:45:03.689: E/AndroidRuntime(27805):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
01-17 14:45:03.689: E/AndroidRuntime(27805):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-17 14:45:03.689: E/AndroidRuntime(27805):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-17 14:45:03.689: E/AndroidRuntime(27805): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
01-17 14:45:03.689: E/AndroidRuntime(27805):    at android.media.MediaPlayer._stop(Native Method)
01-17 14:45:03.689: E/AndroidRuntime(27805):    at android.media.MediaPlayer.stop(MediaPlayer.java:977)
01-17 14:45:03.689: E/AndroidRuntime(27805):    at  ABC.map.MapActivity.onPause(MapActivity.java:170)
01-17 14:45:03.689: E/AndroidRuntime(27805):    at android.app.Activity.performPause(Activity.java:4564)
01-17 14:45:03.689: E/AndroidRuntime(27805):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause(Instrumentation.java:1195)
01-17 14:45:03.689: E/AndroidRuntime(27805):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2696)
01-17 14:45:03.689: E/AndroidRuntime(27805):    ... 12 more
```

Comment: Please post your logcat and the relevant code. Thanks.

Comment: yeah sure jus wait for min. I will post it

Comment: Override the onBackPressed() method inside the A2 activity and start the activity through intent.

Comment: Ok got your point. But another point is that when I click from A2 it will come back to A1 but then if try to come back to A1 from A2 it's giving this error.

Comment: Before that finish your A2 activity when you press backbutton from A2 activity.No need back press bcoz A1 is ur main activity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens because your `A2 Activity` is not started. 
You need to check that `onCreate()` and `onStart()` method are finished in your `A2 Activity` and only after that you have to start `A3 Activity`.

Comment: Thank you for your quick help sir. I am not getting your point.It showing UI for A2 then how can I say that A2 is not started. and A3 to A2 on back press working properly only from A2 toA1 not working. mean (A2 to A1 working ) . But (A3 to A2 to A1 not working.). Is there any solution for this?

Comment: May be yuo have an exception in MapActivity.onPause() method?

Comment: What If I use clear top for both A2 and A3. Because its not necessary for me to retain these two when I click on back. Is it ok ?

Comment: Yes I got the problem. there was problem in on pause of A2. Thank you for helping.