# Unable to stop MusicPlayer even after finishing an Activity.

Tags: java, android

I've set MediaPlayer to play different songs. However, when I try to close the Application, the Activity gets closed, but the song still run in the Background. Here is how I've coded it!

```
    try {
        mp.setDataSource(text);
        mp.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.start();
            }
        });

        mp.prepare();
        mp.setVolume(0.4f, 0.4f);

        songPlayer.setDataSource(song);
        songPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer songPlayer) {
                songPlayer.start();
            }
        });

        songPlayer.prepare();
        songPlayer.setLooping(true);

        voicePlayer.setDataSource(voice);

        voicePlayer.setLooping(true);
        voicePlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer voicePlayer) {
                voicePlayer.start();
            }
        });
        voicePlayer.prepare();
        voicePlayer.setVolume(0.5f,0.5f);

    }
    catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    catch (IllegalMonitorStateException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //THIS IS WHERE I THINK THE ERROR IS : 
    //WHERE `mp` IS LOOPED WITH DELAY OF 5000ms
    try {
        final Handler hlr = new Handler();

        final Runnable looper = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                if (mp != null) {

                    if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                        mp.stop();
                    }

                }


                mp.start();

            }
        };


        mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                hlr.postDelayed(looper, 5000);
            }
        });

    }
    catch(IllegalStateException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }



    }


}
```

And there is also One method which restarts the activity after a specified time. And the code for that Activity is :

```
public void snoozeup(View view)
{
    SharedPreferences sa = getSharedPreferences("SnoozeList", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int snox = sa.getInt("SnoozeX",0);

    if(snox==2) {

        Handler handler = new Handler();
        Runnable x = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Time_Date.this, Time_Date.class);
                intent.putExtra("finisher", state);

                startActivity(intent);

            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(x, 120000);

    }


    else
    {
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        Runnable x = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                startActivity(new Intent(Time_Date.this, Time_Date.class));
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(x, 180000);

    }

    try
    {
        if (mp != null && mp.isPlaying())
        {
            Log.d("TAG------->", "mp is running");
            mp.stop();
            Log.d("TAG------->", "mp is stopped");
            mp.reset();
            mp.release();
            Log.d("TAG------->", "mp is released");
            mp=null;
        }

        if (voicePlayer != null && voicePlayer.isPlaying()) {
            Log.d("TAG------->", "voiceplayer is running");
            voicePlayer.stop();
            Log.d("TAG------->", "voiceplayer is stopped");
            voicePlayer.release();
            Log.d("TAG------->", "voiceplayer is released");
        }


        if (songPlayer != null && songPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            Log.d("TAG------->", "songplayer is running");
            songPlayer.stop();
            Log.d("TAG------->", "songplayer is stopped");
            songPlayer.release();
            Log.d("TAG------->", "songplayer is released");
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    finish();
}
```

The problem is with `mp` . Other instances of MediaPlayer gets stopped. But not `mp`. And sadly, Can't see any error in logcat as well. So where am I doing wrong? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Where do you handle the activity being paused/stopped?

Comment: I do not handle it, Should I do it? Here is my complete activity code: https://etherpad.mozilla.org/VEh8bsOCZO  . As a beginner, I am having trouble fixing this. If you can explain what must be done, it'll be much helpful :)

Comment: Yes, you stop the player in onResume() for example, so that it stops when the activity is paused

Comment: And where should I use onResume() ?

Comment: Try this code: @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mp!= null) {
            //destroy your object here!
        }
    }

Comment: onResume is a method of the activity, you override it

Comment: @TimCastelijns And so , should I call the method to end it ?

Comment: no that is not the point, go read the link WannaGetHigh posted below

Comment: @TimCastelijns okay, BTW why should I use onPause() , what about onStop() ?

Comment: @oblivion just read through that link he posted and it will become clear

Answer (score 1):

You are destroying your activity, but you need to stop/destroy your media player too. Please write down the following code in your activity.

```
@Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mp!= null) {
         //destory ur object here.   
        }
    }
```

Comment: You might want to read [How Do I Write A Good Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Just explaining how to do things really doesn't help anybody to understand what went wrong.

Comment: Edit your answer *now* ;)

Comment: hope its better than previous :)

Answer (score 1):

In order to stop the music you should put this code in the `onPause()` method.

This method can be overrided from your class that inherite from `Activity`

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mp.stop
}
```

You can also take a look at [Managing the Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html) to better understand how an activity is managed by Android.

Comment: Unable to pause activity {zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia.Time_Date}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No activity
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3260)

Comment: @oblivion where does this happens ? In your main activity ? Or somewhere else ? I searched for your error and it leads me to this -> [Unable to pause activity exception in android](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21182257/3612559)

Answer (score 0):

Put in either `onPause()` or `onDestroy()` Example:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mp.stop();
}
```